# Cloud SQL Horizontal Scaling

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud, google-cloud-spanner

Is cloud spanner the only solution for horizontal scaling of mysql instances on the google cloud? Is there a way to scale in cloud sql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Albert Cui stated, Cloud Spanner does not have a horizontally-scaling MySQL database behind it, but rather a different implementation that is a transactional, ACID relational database with strong consistency, accepts SQL (though it's not fully compliant with SQL), is globally distributed and scales horizontally.

For more information you can consult [the Cloud Spanner documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/)

About Cloud SQL, you can scale read capacity horizontally with read replicas, and it can scale vertically (that is, increase the hardware capacity of the instance in which it runs) with no more effort than choosing an instance of a higher tier and only a couple of minutes of downtime. Keep in mind that it doesn't scale automatically, and it can't scale memory, CPU power or capacity independently, you need to choose from [predefined instance tiers](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#2nd-gen-instance-pricing).

According to [this article by Google](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/horizontally-scale-mysql-database-backend-with-google-cloud-sql-and-proxysql), you can scale Cloud SQL horizontally by using the MySQL implementation and [ProxySQL](http://proxysql.com/). However, keep in mind that this goes beyond the Cloud SQL managed service.

For more information you can consult [the Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/)

Answer (score 5):

Cloud Spanner doesn't scale MySQL in that it isn't a drop-in replacement, but it is itself a horizontally scaling relational database.

You can add [read replicas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/create-replica) in CloudSQL to scale your reads.